# Dart encoding / decoding Class's not working

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting this out put when use the encode function `"{\"2023-04-19 00:00:00.000Z\":[{\"title\":\"sdaads\"}]}"` but when i try to decode it i am getting this error `[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'` I tried many things but none of them helped me

The main problem is that i can't convert string to Map variable.
I use the chatGPT for that data convert functions. it did pretty well but i couldn't fixed decoding my self

```dart
class Event{
  final String title;
  Event({required this.title});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'title': title,
  };

  factory Event.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Event(
      title: json['title'],
    );
  }
}

class CalendarPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CalendarPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CalendarPage> createState() => _CalendarPageState();
}

class _CalendarPageState extends State<CalendarPage> {

  String encodeSelectedEvents(Map<DateTime, List<Event>> selectedEvents) {
    Map<String, List<Map<String, dynamic>>> encodedEvents = {};
    selectedEvents.forEach((key, value) {
      encodedEvents[key.toString()] = value.map((event) => event.toJson()).toList();
    });
    return json.encode(encodedEvents);
  }

  Map<DateTime, List<Event>> decodeSelectedEvents(String jsonString) {
    Map<String, dynamic> decodedEvents = json.decode(jsonString);
    Map<DateTime, List<Event>> selectedEvents = {};
    decodedEvents.forEach((key, value) {
      DateTime dateTimeKey = DateTime.parse(key);
      selectedEvents[dateTimeKey] = List<Event>.from(value.map((event) => Event.fromJson(event)));
    });
    return selectedEvents;
  }

  Map<DateTime, List<Event>>? selectedEvents = {};

  DateTime today = DateTime.now();

  void _OnDaySelected(DateTime day, DateTime focusedDay) {
    setState(() {
      today = day;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    initializeDateFormatting("tr_TR");
    selectedEvents = {};
  }

  List<Event> _getEventsfromDay(DateTime day) {
    return selectedEvents![day]?? [];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TableCalendar(
                locale: "tr_TR",
                firstDay: DateTime.utc(2023, 01, 01),
                lastDay: DateTime.utc(2025, 01, 01),
                focusedDay: today,
                headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
                  formatButtonVisible: false,
                  titleCentered: true,
                ),
                availableGestures: AvailableGestures.all,
                rowHeight: 35,
                onDaySelected: _OnDaySelected,
                selectedDayPredicate: (day) =>isSameDay(day,today),
                eventLoader: _getEventsfromDay,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: () async{

                final secim = await Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (builder) => EventAddPage(date: today.toString().split(" ")[0],))); // returns a string or false
                if (secim != false) {
                  print(secim);
                  final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

                  var events = prefs.getString('events');
                  print(events);
                  // if its first time creating
                  if (events == null){
                    await prefs.setString("events", "{}");
                    selectedEvents = {};
                  }else {
                    print("control 1");
                    print(events);
                    selectedEvents = decodeSelectedEvents(events);
                  }
                  print(selectedEvents);
                  //print("first : " + json.encode(encodeSelectedEvents(selectedEvents!)));
                  

                  if (selectedEvents == null) {
                    selectedEvents = {today: [Event(title: secim)]};
                  } else if (selectedEvents![today]?.isNotEmpty ?? false) {
                    print("control 2");
                    selectedEvents![today]!.add(Event(title: secim));
                  } else {
                    print("control 3");
                    selectedEvents![today] = [Event(title: secim)];
                  }
                  setState(() {});
                  print("last sectipn");
                  print("last : " + json.encode(encodeSelectedEvents(selectedEvents!)));

                  await prefs.setString("events", json.encode(encodeSelectedEvents(selectedEvents!)));


                }
                },
                  child: Text("Seçili güne event ekle")
              ),
              ..._getEventsfromDay(today).map((Event event) => ListTile(title: Text(event.title),)),

            ],
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: When I copy and paste your code, `decodeSelectedEvents("{\"2023-04-19 00:00:00.000Z\":[{\"title\":\"sdaads\"}]}");` works fine for me.  Can you provide a minimal but complete example that reproduces your problem?

Comment: @jamesdlin I edit the question i hope its readable.

Comment: @pamphlet the questioning is how dart can convert a Map to json with custom variables

Comment: Your code is neither minimal nor complete.  You need to provide complete code that someone can copy-and-paste  and run to reproduce your error.  Minimize your code by removing irrelevant parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

those are worked

```
  Map<DateTime, List<Event>>? selectedEvents = {};

  String encodeSelectedEvents(Map<DateTime, List<Event>> selectedEvents) {
    Map<String, List<Map<String, dynamic>>> encodedEvents = {};
    selectedEvents.forEach((key, value) {
      encodedEvents[key.toString()] = value.map((event) => event.toJson()).toList();
    });
    return json.encode(encodedEvents);
  }

  Map<DateTime, List<Event>> decodeSelectedEvents(String jsonString) {
    final decodedData = json.decode(jsonString);
    final selectedEvents = <DateTime, List<Event>>{};
    decodedData.forEach((key, value) {
      final dateTimeKey = DateTime.parse(key);
      final List<dynamic> eventsData = value;
      final events = eventsData.map((eventData) => Event.fromJson(eventData)).toList();
      selectedEvents[dateTimeKey] = events;
    });
    return selectedEvents;
  }
```